# Arrange the array of elements 0, 1, and 2 so that the array places all 0 in the first places, then all 1s and 2 as last

Tags: c++

I need to Write a C ++ program that prompts the user to enter 10 integers in the array.
Input numbers are: 0, 1 or 2.
The program should extract the array that is entered on the screen Arrange the array of elements 0, 1, and 2 so that the array places all 0 in the first places, then all 1s
and all 2 as the last.
Arranged array displays on the screen.

Have been struggling over this for few hours now. Im stuck and dont know how to show Output .
Input should be for example 0 0 1 0 1 2 2 2 0 1
Output 0000111222
HOW?

```
int main ()
{
  int t [N], i, ;
  cout << "Enter 10 arrays from 0-2" << endl;
  cout << "Original array:";

  for (i = 0; i <N; i ++)
  {
    cin >> t [i];
  }

  if (t [i]> = 0 && t [i] <= 2)
  {
    cout << "Rearranging elements of array:" << ? << endl;
  }
  cout << "End of the program!"

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: So you just need to sort the array?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "how to sort array"?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: Just to let you know, the generic algorithm is described as the [Dutch National Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) or 3-way partition.  The solution is not to sort, but to strategically swap items as you go through the array.

Comment: @bruno I believe that at first glance, it sounds like a simple sort solution, but the question may have something else in mind (like if it isn't ascending numbers, but let's say the order should be 1,0,2 order instead of 0,1,2).  You can't solve that by simply sorting.

Comment: @bruno -- You don't need to do that.  The 3-way partition can be done in a single pass.

Comment: N-way partition is just a 3-way partition repeatedly done on the array (but the start and end indices differ on each pass).

Comment: Then 3-way beats this in that it takes a single pass.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904592/r-g-b-element-array-swap/51905357#51905357).

Comment: @bruno -- Not sure.  It's just an alternative *if* the OP can tell us if the question is asked about a generic solution on how to order 3 items.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie visibly we lost our time ... (I deleted all my remarks being useless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner, you may want to try this (this is the simplest solution I could think of without using other libraries):

```
int main () {
const int size = 10;
int arr[size], temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}
for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < size - j - 1; k++) {
        if(arr[k] > arr[k+1]) {
            temp = arr[k];
            arr[k] = arr[k+1];
            arr[k+1] = temp;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The nested for-loop part simply tells you to sort the elements in an ascending order. It compares two adjacent elements, then swaps the two elements if the value in the "first places" is larger than the other.

Answer (score 2):

when you do

> ```
>  if (t [i]> = 0 && t [i] <= 2)
> ```

`i` equals `N` so you access out of the array, and of course that does not sort the array

You do not check if `cin >> t[i]` success so if the user enter something else than an `int` all the entries from the current will not be set (they will be `0` in case you use a `std::vector`)

---

A first way is to do without taking account the range 0..2, replace `int t[n]` by `std::vector<int> t(N)` and use `sort(t.begin(), t.end())` to sort your array

The complexity is `O(N*log(N))` (here N is 10)

For instance :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define N 10

int main ()
{
  vector<int> t(N);
  size_t i; // size_t the right type for an index

  cout << "Enter 10 values in range 0..2" << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    for (;;) {
      cout << "value #" << i << ':';

      if (!(cin >> t[i])) {
        cerr << "not a number" << endl;
        cin.clear(); // raz error

        string s;

        cin >> s; // skip bad input
      }
      else if ((t[i] < 0) || (t[i] > 2))
        cerr << "value out of range" << endl;
      else
        break;
    }
  }

  cout << "Original array:";
  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) cout << ' ' << t[i]; // old way to do
  cout << endl;

  sort(t.begin(), t.end());

  cout << "Sorted array:";
  for (auto v : t) cout << ' ' << v; // new way to do
  cout << endl;

  cout << "End of the program!" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter 10 values in range 0..2
value #0:aze
not a number
value #0:-2
value out of range
value #0:3
value out of range
value #0:2
value #1:0
value #2:1
value #3:2
value #4:0
value #5:2
value #6:1
value #7:0
value #8:0
value #9:1
Original array: 2 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0 1
Sorted array: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
End of the program!
```

---

A second way considering a range [min .. max] not too large is to count the number of each value then fill the array to respect these counts

The complexity is `O(2N)` (here N is 10)

For instance :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 2
#define N 10

int main ()
{
  vector<int> t(N);
  size_t i; // size_t the right type for an index

  cout << "Enter 10 values in range " << MIN << ".." << MAX << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {

    for (;;) {
      cout << "value #" << i << ':';

      if (!(cin >> t[i])) {
        cerr << "not a number" << endl;
        cin.clear(); // raz error

        string s;

        cin >> s; // skip bad input
      }
      else if ((t[i] < MIN) || (t[i] > MAX))
        cerr << "value out of range" << endl;
      else
        break;
    }
  }

  cout << "Original array:";
  for (auto v : t) cout << ' ' << v;
  cout << endl;

  // count numbers
  vector<size_t> counts(MAX - MIN + 1);

  for (auto v : t) counts[v - MIN] += 1;

  // fill again
  i = 0;

  for (int r = MIN; r <= MAX; ++r) {
    size_t n = counts[r - MIN];

    while (n--) t[i++] = r;
  }

  cout << "Sorted array:";
  for (auto v : t) cout << ' ' << v;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "End of the program!" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s2.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter 10 values in range 0..2
value #0:a
not a number
value #0:3
value out of range
value #0:0
value #1:2
value #2:1
value #3:1
value #4:2
value #5:2
value #6:2
value #7:0
value #8:1
value #9:2
Original array: 0 2 1 1 2 2 2 0 1 2
Sorted array: 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
End of the program!
```

---

Specifically for values between 0 and 2 (in fact for 3 possible values) as said in a remark by @PaulMcKenzie you can use the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) and look at that question : [R G B element array swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904592/r-g-b-element-array-swap)

The complexity is `O(N)` (here N is 10)

Answer (score 0):

1st answer is too difficult for me, im  only beginner not knowing what im doing yet.
2nd answer is to that direction where it should be right but i need to put in that input cant be more than 2 or less than numeber 0, thats the problem now :D 
Im sorry, i just cant get to that point where i understand that syntax.