# How can I group a million numbers faster than using qsort in C++?

Tags: c++, grouping

How can i group a series of integer numbers, eg., [4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4] to become [4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1] without using any sorting algorithm.

Note that i don't need the result to be in any sorted order, but i do need the suggested algorithm to group a million of numbers faster than qsort.

Comment: It might be faster to sort it (say, with `std::sort`) than to do the kind of grouping you suggest.

Comment: What is the range of your numbers?

Comment: The ranges can be wide as the numbers can 8/16/32/64 bits. Actually i need the algorithm to be generalized for float/double or even strings.

Comment: It might worth checking out a hash table based solution. But maybe it will be slower than quicksort because of bad cache utilization.

Comment: @cow This sounds like the n-way partition problem.  If so, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904592/r-g-b-element-array-swap/51905357#51905357).   Applying that algorithm on multiple passes gives you `O(n * m)`, where `m` is the number of data items, and `n` is the number of unique items.

Comment: Why the downvotes? "Unclear what you're asking?" This question is pretty clear to me.

Comment: why bother optimizing with such a small dataset? just stick to std::sort

Comment: @cow -- What does you data set really consist of?  If there are a lot of numbers, but only a few groups, (3, 4, 5, for example), then grouping them using an algorithm designed to group things will usually be faster than sorting the items.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My data set can be integers, floating numbers or strings. And their cardinalities can vary wildly, ie. they can be all unique, all identical and any combination between :)

Comment: @cow No.  What I mean is how many different groups are you expecting?  Your example shows 4 unique group of numbers.  So are you expecting a million numbers and only a few unique groups?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Doesn't the number of different groups depend on cardinality of the data sets? For example, the data set in my question is 4.

Comment: @cow You have 4 unique numbers, and you want all the same numbers to be in a certain order.   That does not require a sort to be done -- is that what you are trying to achieve?  If so, then you want a partitioning algorithm, not sorting (that is, if you want to achieve this without having to allocate extra space).

Comment: same problem, but without the c++ tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579149/can-an-array-be-grouped-more-efficiently-than-sorted

Comment: don't bother optimizing, 1 million numbers can be sorted in <100ms using std::sort

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i just need the same numbers to sit next to each other in the array. No specific order is necessary. Thanks for suggesting std::partition, though i'm not sure how it fits my use case. i need to look into it...

Comment: @skeller Agreed, but i'm just wondering if there is any other algorithms that need not sort the numbers and can be (much) faster :)

Comment: @skellar -- The problem is that `std::sort` won't be nearly enough, since the numbers have to be grouped in a certain order.  That's the wrinkle to the problem.

Comment: @cow -- Looking at your example, you specified a non-sorted grouping.  So should the numbers be grouped in a specific order?  I think that is not clear in what you're asking.  If it is something like what you posted, that is clearly not going to be solved by just a single call to `std::sort`.

Comment: @geza Yeah. My question seems a dup of that. Closing mine.

Comment: alternative/faster algorithm might be bucket-sort, but the improvement depends on the structure of your data.

Comment: [Example of partitioning](https://ideone.com/KJPAzP).  As pointed out, this all depends on the data you have and whether you require a certain grouping.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the example, but i doubt that i can know the `order` vector in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you don't care too much about using extra space. It first stores the number of occurrences of each number in an `unordered_map` and then creates a vector that contains each value in the map, repeated the number of times it was seen in the original `vector`. See the documentation for [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) for how this works. The `[]` operator for an `unordered_map` works in `O(1)` on average. So creating the `unordered_map` takes `O(N)` time. Iterating through the map and populating the return vector again takes `O(N)` time, so this whole thing should run in `O(N)`. Note that this creates two extra copies of the data.

In the worst case, the `[]` operator takes `O(N)` time, so the only way to really know if this is faster than `qsort` would be to measure it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> groupNumbers(const std::vector<int> &input)
{
    std::vector<int> grouped;

    std::unordered_map<int, int> counts;
    for (auto &x: input)
    {
        ++counts[x];
    }

    for (auto &x: counts)
    {
        grouped.insert(grouped.end(), x.second, x.first);
    }
    return grouped;
}

// example
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test{1,2,3,4,3,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,3,2};
    std::vector<int> result(groupNumbers(test));

    for (auto &x: result)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Grouping can be done in basically O(n) using partitioning and using no extra space.

Comment: worth a try but i'd expect this to be slower because of overhead of hashing, the missing memory alignment of map and the copies

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: How? Here you say O(n), under the question you say O(n\*m). O(n\*m) seems OK, but O(n) is not (Note: this solution is O(n) as well, but with a much larger constant factor than qsort likely has).

Comment: It depends on the number of unique groups.  If there are a million numbers and only a few unique groups, then the complexity is `O(n*(m-2))`.  We don't really know what the OP's dataset looks like, but if it's where there are a lot of numbers and only 3 or 4 groups, a grouping algorithm will beat a sorting algorithm.

Comment: did measurement, this takes about 1.5 times longer than std::sort for 1 mio and about 2.5 times longer for 10 mio numbers.

Comment: @skeller Make sure you're testing an optimized (release) build and not an unoptimized (debug) build.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i did, release, /O2