# std::partition to partition a a vector of string

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to use `std::partition` to partition a vector into multiple part based on whitespace.

```cpp
void solution2()
{
    std::vector<string> v{ "10","20","","30","40","50","","60","70" };
    auto i = begin(v);
    while (i != end(v)-1)
    {
        auto it = std::partition(i, end(v)-1, [](auto empty) {return empty != ""; });
        std::copy(i, it, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        i = it;
    }
}
```

For example in the above code I want to partition it into multiple and condition to partition is whitespace `""`

so the vector v should partition to 3 groups

1. "10" "20"
2. "30" "40" "50"
3. "60" "70"

The problem I am facing is in line

```cpp
auto it = std::partition(begin(v), end(v)-1, [](string empty) {return empty != ""; });
```

Error

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) C:\source\repos\out\build\x64-debug\sample  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\xutility  3919
```

Any suggestion what can be changed to fix the error.
Any other efficient way to do the same using `std::range` or `std::view`

Comment: This doesn't look like something `std::partition` is designed to solve.  The `std::partition` has a simple definition -- items that satisfy a condition goes on the left of the partition, and items that do not satisy the condition go on the right of the partition.  It is a binary choice.

Comment: `std::ostream_iterator<int>` should be `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>` to fix the compile error.

Comment: `std::partition` is used to reorder elements. You don't want to change their order at all so it's not the right algorithm for the job.

Comment: @Blastfurnace is it worth trying stable partition https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/stable_partition

Comment: @HariomSingh No, that is not related to what you are trying to do at all. Consider using std::find like my answer outlines.

Comment: @HariomSingh -- I would understand if you were partitioning items into their distinct groups, such as what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904592/r-g-b-element-array-swap/51905357#51905357) does using `std::partition`  But that isn't what you're doing here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes you are right , I got carried away with the name partition .https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/partition .Examples had it partition into two groups

Comment: Again you aren't reordering anything. You are searching for a specific value to identify ranges. What you are doing is more like a "split" algorithm to parse apart ranges. There's no order you can take advantage of so you're left with a linear scan, in this case a `std::find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++20, this can be done trivially with `ranges::split_view`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> v{ "10","20","","30","40","50","","60","70" };

for(auto part : v | std::views::split(""))
{
    for(auto num : part) std::cout << num << ',';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6ezKx7hYq)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to get the next empty string would be more appropriate here.

```cpp
auto i = begin(v), e = end(v);
while (i != e) {
    auto it = std::find(i, e, "");
    std::copy(i, it, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
    if (it == e) break;
    i = it + 1;
}
```